# i need access all axios data after for loop

Tags: node.js, axios, es6-promise

I'm making a simple word combinatiion website.
and as a final step, I need all possible word in one string
so I write code like this

```
const fs=require('fs');
const axios=require('axios')
function test(want){
    const res=axios.get("http://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/"+want);
    const datapromise=res.then((res)=>res.data);
    return datapromise
}
fs.readFile('./input.txt','utf-8',function(error,data){
    //console.log("console log")
    var array=data.toString().split("\n");
    fs.writeFile("./log.txt","",(err)=>{});
    var res=""
    for(i in array){
          test(array[i]).then((data)=>(data)=>res+=data[0].word+"<br>").catch(/*(data)=>console.log(data.code)*/);
    }
    console.log(res);
})
```

But this code isn't work. console.log(res); is executed first and followed by for loop.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I've gone ahead and answered here - there *was* enough detail to spot the issue; however, I'd note that the code may have been considered not minimal enough for some. In addition, there were some simple code issues like the way `then` and `catch` we're called. Especially with async logic like this - i recommend investigating every input/output of every function called even if there are multiple functions called on each line. I also recommend getting familiar with node's debugging tools here - could help ya get to a resolution more quickly! Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about Axios I can tell that `axios.get` and therefore the `test` function is going to be async. This means `console.log` here will always run first here as a result. Test ends up returning a `promise` that will resolve at a later time.

I'd do something like this (assuming you don't have async/await available):

```
var res= "";
var promises = [];
for(i in array) {
  promises.push(
    test(array[i]).then((data) => res+=data[0].word + "<br>")
  );
}
Promise.all(promises).finally(() => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Other notes:

1. The `catch` here is being called but nothing is being passed in - this may result in an error
2. The `then` has a nested function that I imagine wouldn't ever be called `(data) => (data) =>` this is basically creating a 2nd nested function. I don't think it'd get called.

Comment: thanks. althought i slove this different way by using promise.allsettid.
but i will try this one beacus this is more simple